# One database or several?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I am developing a CRM in Laravel and the following doubts came to me.

Client A will have access to 1 database + 5Gb of emails and Client B will also, but how should I organize this on my server?

Should I create a database called `banco_a` and another `banco_b`? Is there another way?

If anyone can give me a "north" of which would be the best way for this, I will be grateful.

Remembering that my application could reach 100 clients or 1000

Comment: Separated databases wouldn't be a problem, I think the deployment process is key here. How are you doing your deployments?

Comment: maybe you can try to research about multi tenant database

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirements you have to implement multi-tenancy system, ie architecture in which a single instance of a software application serves multiple customers, for detail read this article https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/multi-tenancy,

In laravel there is package for multitenancy. https://laravel-tenancy.com, which is awesome in my knowledge.